# GIT: commit to --bare origin master when I'm developing on the same machine in which the private server is running?

Tags: git, ubuntu, repository

I've created a local git server on ubuntu so other developers can contribute on LAN. I'm developing on that same server. I'm logged as root user. The repository is in **opt/git/directory.git** . How should I set the origin to commit from that same pc?(it's a --bare repository). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the remote URL of origin like this:

```
git remote set-url origin /opt/git/directory.git
```

Or, when initially cloning:

```
git clone /opt/git/directory.git
```

Just use the "normal" path.

From [the Git clone docs:](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)

> For local repositories, also supported by Git natively, the following
>   syntaxes may be used:
>
> ```
> /path/to/repo.git/
>
> file:///path/to/repo.git/
> ```
>
> These two syntaxes are mostly equivalent, except the former implies
>   --local option.

But please don't be logged in as root when doing so. Give the directory `/opt/git/directory.git` appropriate
access rights instead, so everybody (in a certain group), including yourself, can push to it.

You may also use the same URL that your coworkers use, e.g. `http://path/to/repo.git` (or whatever you've told them would work).

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a working tree to let you contribute to the project.

To resume basically git **--bare is for sharing**.   --bare repo doesn't contains a working directory.

So to work on the same machine:

- move out the --bare repo
- $ git clone pathtoyour.git
- start working and push (git will give you the info to setup the origin if not set).

ps: you should avoid to use root user.